# Re-using Java generic collections in Scala without trait Object

Tags: java, scala, generics, collections, traits

I'm trying to re-use a Java generic collection I wrote, looks a lot like this:

```
public class Blah<T>
   implements List<T>
{
...
   public void test(T[] array) {
   ...
   }
...
}
```

When consumed from a Scala generic collection that uses the above, I'm getting a compilation error, where I notice that the Blah class method expects not T, but T with java.lang.Object!

```
Object MyStaticObject {
   def test[T](array: Array[T]) = { 
      val x = new Blah[T]();
      x.test(array) // <- error here: Overloaded method with alternatives test[T with java.lang.Object] ... cannot be applied
}
```

Is there a way to avoid this situation without re-writing the Blah class in Scala? (That works, but I have too much such Java code and rather not port the whole thing...)

Maybe perhaps some kind of implicit definition could come to the rescue?
Thanks!

Comment: This looks a lot like a type erasure thing caused by using generic arrays in the first place?

Comment: I think you meant `x.test(array)`, right?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Restricting `def test[T <: AnyRef]` does the trick.

Rightly so, the generic java method should not accept , e.g., an `int[]` (`Array[Int]`) parameter. 
`Blah[Int]` will be taken as `Blah<Integer>`, `Array[Int]` is `int[]`, which is not `Integer[]`.